# How to combine mean and count value frequency in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, kaggle

I am working on the [Tianic Data set](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic). I am examining the frequency of survivors based on their title and how frequent each of those titles occur.

`train[['Title', 'Survived']].groupby(['Title'], as_index=False).mean().sort_values(by='Survived',ascending=False)`

[image]

and

`train.Title.value_counts(normalize=True)`

[image]

Is there any chance that two can be combined and I see one table as a result? I'd like to have the following as my final table:

[image]

I am not sure how to use aggregate functions count and mean together in the way I want. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `reindex` and assign it back

```
#df1=train[['Title', 'Survived']].groupby(['Title'], as_index=False).mean().sort_values(by='Survived',ascending=False)
#s=train.Title.value_counts(normalize=True)

df1['Title Freq']=s.reindex(df1.Title).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider named aggregations with [**`agg`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and a user-defined method since [**`Series.values_count`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) is not exposed as its own method. To avoid the collision of *title* in column names, call `reset_index` at the end instead of `as_index=False` at start:

```
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv(...)
train['title'] = train['name'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)\.', expand=False)
train['title'] = train['title'].where(train['title'].isin(['Mrs','Miss','Mr','Master']), 'Others')

def value_counts(g):
    return(g.value_counts())

agg_df = (train.groupby(['title'])
               .agg(survived_mean = ('survived', 'mean'),
                    title_values_counts = ('title', value_counts))
               .sort_values(by='survived_mean', ascending=False)
               .reset_index()
         )

print(agg_df)    
#     title  survived_mean  title_values_counts
# 0     Mrs       0.786802                  197
# 1    Miss       0.676923                  260
# 2  Master       0.508197                   61
# 3  Others       0.441176                   35
# 4      Mr       0.162483                  757
```